# Is it acceptable to plant turmeric vertically?

Tags: planting, ginger

Will tumeric that you plant with the "stick, hole, cover" method grow well vertically?

Basically my planting method is to break off a piece of clean dead stick, push it in the ground, put the turmeric in the ground, then cover it up.

Comment: "sick, hole, cover" is jam a stick into the soil, to make a hole, insert root segment and cover? It would be a good idea to elaborate on what you mean.